# How to convert the json array to string array in android?

Tags: android, arrays, json, string

I am converting an json array to string array thats doesn't exist any tag. I tried with all tricks but not succeeded.

**json array:-**

"validValues":["01_Abacus","02_AlarmClock","03_Basketball","04_Beaker","55_Watch"]

**Code for convert the json array to string values**

```
if (jsonComponentObj.has(TAG_VALID_VALUES)) {
                    String value = jsonComponentObj.getString(TAG_VALID_VALUES);
                    Logs.e("value " + value);
                    if (!value.equals("null")) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonComponentObj
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_VALID_VALUES);

                        if (jsonArray != null) {
                            ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray
                                            .getJSONObject(j);
                                    stringArray.add(jsonObject.toString());
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Logs.e("Exception: "+e.toString());
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
```

**Exception:**

```
org.json.JSONException: Value 01_Abacus at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

If anyone have idea. Please reply. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Because `validValues` JSONArray contain only Strings instead of `JSONObject`.so get all values from JSONArray as:

```
for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {

           String str_value = jsonArray.optString(j);
           stringArray.add(str_value);

   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. Try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Your json array contains `Strings` not `json object`.Therefore to get Strings from json array directly use `getString()`,So 
Change

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
stringArray.add(jsonObject.toString());
```

to

```
 stringArray.add(jsonArray.getString(j));
```

or

```
stringArray.add(jsonArray.optString(j));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`optString(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#optString(int)) to coerce a string value from array. Using `getString(int)` would cause problems if ever the values in the array were not strings.

```
for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
    String value = jsonArray.optString(j);
    stringArray.add(value);     
}
```

If you want to give a default value, use [`optString(int, String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#optString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

try `JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getString(j);`

instead of `JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);`